# I am trying to fetch data with NextJS but I keep getting this error -- Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fetch')

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to fetch data from NextJS from sanity but I have encountered an error and I cannot seem to resolve what it is. I have attached a screenshot of the code snippets.

```
import React from 'react';
import { client } from '../library/client';

import { Cart, Footer, FooterBanner, HeroBanner, Layout, NavBar, Product } from '../components/index.js';

const Home = ({ products, bannerData }) => {
  return (
   <>
    <HeroBanner />
    {console.log(bannerData)}
    <div>
      <h1 className="products-heading">Best Selling Products</h1>
      <p>Speakers of very many variations</p>
    </div>

    <div className='products-container'>
      {
        products?.map((product) => product.name)
      }
    </div>

    <Footer />
   </>
  )
}

export const getServerSideProps = async () => {
  const query = '*[_type == "product"]';
  const products = await client.fetch(query);

  const bannerQuery = '*[_type == "banner"]';
  const bannerData = await client.fetch(bannerQuery);

  return {
    props: { products, bannerData }
  }
}
export default Home;
```

Here is the client.js file that contains the source code for the sanity database.

```
import sanityClient from '@sanity/client';
import imageUrlBuilder from '@sanity/image-url';

const client = sanityClient( {
    projectId: 's0331zgs',
    dataset: 'production',
    apiVersion: '2022-07-05',
    useCdn: true,
    token: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_TOKEN
});


const builder = imageUrlBuilder(client);

export const urlFor = (source)=> {
    builder.image(source);
}
```

Comment: Apparently your import from "../library/client" is returning undefined. That way, you can't access the property "fetch" from client as it's undefined. Can you edit the answer to add the code from "../library/client"?

Comment: Alright, let me provide the client file.

Answer (score 0):

You're not exporting "client" from you "client.js" file. So when you try to import it using `import { client } from '../library/client';`, "client" is undefined.

It should be like this:

```js
export const client = sanityClient( {
    projectId: 's0331zgs',
    dataset: 'production',
    apiVersion: '2022-07-05',
    useCdn: true,
    token: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_TOKEN
});
```